# How to return complete line of string from text file using Java

Tags: java

So I'm trying to write a java application where I have a text file containing some data like: id, username, password and each record is on a new line. What I'm trying to achieve is say for example if the user enters "vick" I want to be able to search the text file for the username that has "vick" in it and return the id, username, password.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class tests {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Vick\\PT\\Tests\\src\\users.txt");
        String[] UserToken = null;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        int lineCount = 0;
        while(br.readLine() != null)
        {
            lineCount++;
        }
        br.close();
        Scanner inputeFile = new Scanner(file);

        int uid = 0;
        String username = null;
        String password = null;

        while(inputeFile.hasNext())
        {
            String str = inputeFile.nextLine();
            UserToken = str.split(",");

            uid = Integer.parseInt(UserToken[0]);
            username = UserToken[1];
            password = UserToken[2];

            //Users u1 = new Users(uid, username, password);
            //System.out.println(UserToken[0] + " - " + UserToken[1] + " - " + UserToken[2]);
        }
        Users u1 = new Users(uid, username, password);
        Scanner search = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Search for user: ");
        String searchterm = search.next();

        while(inputeFile.hasNext())
        {
            if(u1.getUsername().contains(searchterm))
            {
                System.out.println("HE!");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and this is the Users class I'm trying to use with it

```
public class Users {
    public int userid;
    public static String username;
    public String password;

    public Users(int userid, String username, String password)
    {
        userid = userid;
        username = username;
        password = password;
    }

    public int getUID()
    {
        return userid;
    }

    public static String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

-- As someone in this thread already said, use hasNextLine()
-- Your code is not efficient. (First you loop through all lines just to get count and then loop them again to read). My code can be improved too but I will leave that as an exercise.
-- Sample file against which I tested

```
1,test,lol
2,robot,small
```

--

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Tests {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner search = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Search for user: ");
        String searchterm = search.next();


        File file = new File("/tmp/users.txt");
        String[] UserToken = null;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        Scanner inputeFile = new Scanner(file);

        int uid = 0;
        String username = null;
        String password = null;

        while(inputeFile.hasNext())
        {
            String str = inputeFile.nextLine();
            UserToken = str.split(",");

            uid = Integer.parseInt(UserToken[0]);
            username = UserToken[1];
            password = UserToken[2];

            // make user object here if you want to
            if (username.contains(searchterm))
            {
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So I wasn't far off from getting this right? thanks helped a lot

Comment: No problem. You look like a beginner to Java. Hang in there. You were not far off.